# VSCode Marketplace extension: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, zip, marketplace

I am trying to install a VSIX package downloaded from the Marketplace using `wget` on a Linux VM where the VSCode server is installed but I am getting the below error:

```
$ wget -nv https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage -o vspackage.vsix
$ code --install-extension vspackage.vsix
Installing extensions on SSH: boozy-olive-harrier...
Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
Failed Installing Extensions: vscode-remote://ssh-remote%2Bboozy-olive-harrier/root/vspackage.vsix
```

Downloading the file with Firefox on Windows and using the "Install from VSIX..." button inside the VSCode client ([ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix)) works as expected.

The URL I am using is this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage

I compared the md5sum of the downloaded files and I don't get the same if I download the file from Windows or Linux:

**Linux VM:**

- `wget`

```
$ wget -nv https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage
2021-02-09 16:50:08 URL:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage [1270960/1270960] -> "vspackage" [1]
$ du -sk vspackage
1244    vspackage
$ md5sum vspackage
10f6bdb1151a954a702f8a6db6f3bd52  vspackage
```

**Windows:**

- Firefox: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd

```
> certutil.exe -hashfile .\llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd-0.1.9.vsix MD5
MD5 hash of .\llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd-0.1.9.vsix:
74f82f716616796157bde8008c8e5a45
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

- Powershell

```
> Invoke-WebRequest https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage -OutFile vspackage
> Get-ChildItem .\vspackage | % {[int]($_.length / 1kb)}
1383
> certutil.exe -hashfile .\vspackage MD5
MD5 hash of .\vspackage:
74f82f716616796157bde8008c8e5a45
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

The hash of the downloaded file is not the same even though the download URL is.

It seems I am missing a few bytes on Linux which would explain the *Corrupt ZIP* error.

Does somebody understand what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the URL you supplied

```
$ wget -nv https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage
2021-02-11 09:04:22 URL:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage [1270960/1270960] -> "vspackage"
```

Let's see what `vspackage` is

```
$ file vspackage
vspackage: gzip compressed data, max speed, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), original size modulo 2^32 1416661
```

That isn't a zip, it is a compressed gzip file. Let's uncompress that

```
$ mv vspackage vspackage.gz
$ gunzip -v vspackage.gz
vspackage.gz:    10.3% -- replaced with vspackage
```

What is `vspackage` now ?

```
$ file vspackage
vspackage: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Finally, a zip file.

Comment: You are right and I feel silly now... I did not even check the downloaded file type.

```
$ wget -nv https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vsextensions/vscode-clangd/latest/vspackage -O vspackage.vsix.gz
$ gunzip vspackage.vsix.gz
$ code --install-extension vspackage.vsix
Installing extensions on SSH: crappy-heliotrope-tamarin...
Extension 'vspackage.vsix' was successfully installed.
```

I am not sure however why I get a compressed archived with `wget` and not using `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the problem!