# can't install python extension in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install  python extension in vscode latest version and I can't it
show to me `Error while installing 'Python' extension. Please check the log for more details.`
the output in log is

```
[2022-08-25 21:34:08.006] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: Invalid: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at Q.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Zakaria/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169227)
at async Q.doRun (vscode-file://vscodeapp/c:/Users/Zakaria/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:168169)
[2022-08-25 21:37:57.509] [renderer1] [error] ["Invalid: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at Q.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Zakaria/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169227)","    at async Q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Zakaria/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:168169)"]
[2022-08-25 21:37:57.516] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: Invalid: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at Q.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Zakaria/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169227)
    at async Q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Zakaria/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:168169)
```

I am trying to install manually
using this command after download extension but i get t same problem

`code --install-extension ms-python.python-2022.12.1.vsix`
so I uninstall vscode and delete the file extension and reinstall again but I get the same problem .

> can any one help me ????

Comment: have a look at your question title

Comment: why ?? What's in the title?

Comment: You have a complete [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) by visualstudio on how to install phyton on VSC.

Comment: I suppose you already have python installed? Else do that first. Maybe you can download an old version from here and try that https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python. Also try to delete the file doenloaded by vs code. Might it was corrupted on download and vs code wont try to redownload it because its already in their downloads folder? Try to always use the extensions tab to install. Good luck

Comment: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66134532/vscode-marketplace-extension-corrupt-zip-end-of-central-directory-record-signa. Im sure its the solution

Comment: There are also several issues like this on the vscode github that had mainly to do with firewall  or proxy server

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the file "ms-python.python-xxxx.x.x.vsix" for manual installation. [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) (menu navigation 'Version History')
2. Turn off the internet on your computer.
3. Install the file "ms-python.python-хххх.х.х.vsix" through the menu "install from VSIX...".

It helped me.

Answer (score -4):

If you install these extensions on vscode and it gives an error, change the net!
I can install add-ons without problems with the first mobile net, but not with other nets (especially ADSL).
If you don't have the first mobile note available, try F-Y-L-T-R Shekan with the same note.